# Is there a way to use @MockBean annotation while working with Spock framework

Tags: spring-boot, spock, spring-test-mvc

I was trying out Spock and encountered an interesting problem when writing controller-tests.

```
WebMvcTest(value = SomeController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles(value = "restapi")
@Import(value = SecurityConfiguration)
class AccountBalanceControllerTest extends Specification {

@Autowired
SomeController someController

@MockBean
SomeService someService

def "lets test it" {
  given: 
      someService.findAllByName(_) >> ["Some", "Work"]
  when:
    def response = mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/someName/545465?fast=false").with(user("mvc-test").roles("SOME_ACCOUNTS")))
  then: 
      response.andExpect(status().isOk()) 
}


}
```

So the problem is mocking method on `SomeService` instance does not work because it uses a different Mock class for mocking the instance of `SomeService`  class. I got a work around using the static Mock method from Spock in the setup and then using a setter to set `SomeService` in the controller. My question is there any elegant way to use `@MockBean` with Spock `Specification` testing.

Answer (score 16):

You should use [@SpringBean](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/module_spring.html#_using_code_springbean_code) instead of `@MockBean`. As its javadoc says:

> Inspired by Springs @MockBean, but adapted to Spock semantics